# How to pass variables to a jQuery Plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a jQuery plugin that someone helped me write.  I originally only needed it for one use so hardcoded the textbox value lookup directly in the plugin, but now I would like to pass that variable in from where I call it so I can reuse the same plugin multiple times.

Here is what I have, I will post both plugins so you will see what I have done to get it to work side by side.  I would like to pass in the UserSearch: variable instead of hard coding it.

```
(function ($) {
$.checkMultipleUsers = (function (my) {
    my.CheckUsers = function () {
            return $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost:52350/FabRouting/Webservice/UserList.asmx/GetUserCount",
                data: JSON.stringify({ UserSearch: $("[id$=txtSubmittedBy]").val() }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
            });
    };
    return my;
})({});
})(jQuery);
```

and

```
(function ($) {
$.checkMultipleUsers2 = (function (my) {
    my.CheckUsers2 = function () {

        return $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:52350/FabRouting/Webservice/UserList.asmx/GetUserCount",
            data: JSON.stringify({ UserSearch: $("[id$=txtOther]").val() }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
        });

    };
    return my;
})({});
})(jQuery);
```

And I call it like this:

```
promise = $.checkMultipleUsers.CheckUsers();
                    promise.success(function (count) {
}
```

and

```
promise2 = $.checkMultipleUsers2.CheckUsers2();
                    promise2.success(function (count) {
}
```

Also, while I have posted this plugin, is it written well?  I don't understand why it needs both the checkMultipleUsers and the CheckUsers.  It seems like it is a function embedded in another function and I don't understand why.

Comment: This is really not a jQuery plugin. You've simply namespaced a function onto `$`. The vast majority of jQuery plugins attach to `$.fn` so that they are available to every object returned by `$()`.

Comment: @MattBall if you attached this to `$.fn` I still wouldn't call it a jQuery plugin :P

Comment: OK, I am sorry for calling it a plugin. That is what I was told it was and the reason I needed to do that was so I could call it from another unrelated js file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really a jQuery plugin, this can be done with just a normal function.

```
function CheckUsers(searchValue){
        return $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:52350/FabRouting/Webservice/UserList.asmx/GetUserCount",
            data: JSON.stringify({ UserSearch: searchValue}),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json"
        });
}
```

Then you can just call it like `CheckUsers($('#myInput').val());`

Comment: I was told it was a jQuery plugin and that I needed to do it this way so I could call the function from a different js file.  Can I still just pass the variable like you have shown with it still wrapped in the outer checkMultipleUsers?  Again, the reason I was told I needed to do that was so I could call it from a separate js file.

Comment: OK, I went ahead and did that and it worked.  Thanks.  Since this really isn't a jQuery plugin as I have been told, is there another cleaner way to write this function so it can be accessed from other functions in other js files?

Comment: As long as both files are referenced in the same page and the function you're trying to call is within scope there shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Well go figure... I went and used your code exactly and it works as well.  I had trouble with being able to access this code from a different function in a different js file when I was writing it and I was told that I had to "make it a jQuery plugin" and they gave me this code.  It started working then.... but must have been something else. By the way, I have looked at instructions on how to create a jQuery plugin and I see the structure is way different - thanks for pointing that out, I wouldn't have gone and looked :)